# How come can't read the data from SqlLiteDatabase in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.example.abc2/databases/DB_BusData", null, 0);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Tbl_Driver", null);
    String username = c.getString(0).trim();
    String password = c.getString(1).trim();
    //Log.d(username, "try");
    db.close();
```

this is connecting to my DB_BusData in my assets folder,
anything wrong with my code?

p/s: I don't like to use DatabaseHelper.java or what, that is too complicated code. i just want a simply database connection and bind it to my Spinner

Comment: It is not clear post.

Comment: `DatabaseHelper.java` is the SQLite **Open** Helper which is useful if you need to open your database file in a specific way (including upgrading the database schema). It's not meant to be a complicated thing and everyone that puts code to access the data in subclasses is doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the cursor to a position before you can read from it:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.example.abc2/databases/DB_BusData", null, 0);
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Tbl_Driver", null);
if(c.moveToFirst()) {
    String username = c.getString(0).trim();
    String password = c.getString(1).trim();
    //Log.d(username, "try");
}
db.close();
```

P.S. This database is *not* in your `assets` folder. I'm assuming that your file resides on the local device at the path you specified and that it opens successfully

Comment: @RGrahim Any ideas to replace the column index with Column Name?

Comment: `c.getColumnIndex("UsernameField")` will return the index of the specified column

Comment: how to make my database in my assets folder? can show how to bind the data into Spinner?

Comment: @Rgrahim i have copied the DB_BusData into assets folder already

Comment: That's a job for a good tutorial. Any code I could post here wouldn't be detailed enough for you to be able to learn from - http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/21-android-tutorial-spinners?start=2